Importing LTSpice Library or Component model from Github to LTspice 24 and above
I have asked this question last year and I got answers that worked. But not anymore.
Instead of having my library on my machine which runs LTSpice, I want to put them on the cloud, something like Github, where I save all my library components, models and symbols and import them to my LTspice where ever I am and share them with others. LTspice has .inc and .lib directives to import models from a URL, for example: .inc http://www.company.com/models/library.lib
LTSpice says "Could not open Include file"
I was including it from github as .inc http://raw.githubusercontent.com/wissa/LTSpice/main/MyLib/Diodes/1N4001.txt
and it was working but not now.

Can you explain how this might be a relevant EE question.

LTspice is EE simulator

@Wissa Yes, LTspice is a circuit simulator. But you did not explain in which way managing LTspice component library in a custom fashion using Github is related to EE.

Good question and valid. The same claim might be made by other communities who I might forward this question to and they might say .. We don't use LTspice or even know it ... so EE is where good mindes who can work out coding things while knowing LTspice. I hope I cleared it .... If its 51% relevant more than others so it is ok

@Wissa This isn't a "coding thing". Also if I click your link, the file is not there so no program can fetch it. Click the RAW file link to get the direct link to file. However, if github changes their URLs how to directly fetch a file, solving that is not in any way an EE question. So this isn't about LTSpice. Any program that fetches files directly, like a web browser, would have the same issue.

@all - Hi, Historically this site has accepted questions on usage of EE tools (LTspice, Kicad, Altium, Micro-Cap to name a few). We aren't going to be the only place those questions could be asked. We may not even be the best place. But the people using those tools (and therefore the people who may be able to help) are going to be EEs. || If someone wants to start a topic on our [meta] about no longer accepting questions about EE-related software, that would be the way to see if there is support for disallowing those questions in  the future, or not.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not a problem of using LTSpice, when URLs from where to download files are incorrect. The URLs would be incorrect for any other program as well, like for a web browser which could not download the file.

@Justme - Hi, I'm not trying to solve the question in comments. However re: "it's not a problem of using LTSpice, when URLs from where to download files are incorrect" The attempt to link to the .lib file via a github.com link seems flawed, yes. However I didn't see the OP claim that this approach ever worked. However the attempt to link to the .txt file at raw.githubusercontent.com does work for me in a browser (after removing the trailing "), so I'm not sure why you say a browser could not download the file - unless you're referring to the .lib file syntax in the question.

the links has been fixed, a quotation mark was there by mistake

@SamGibson I clicked on OPs link and my browser was sent a 404 page of GitHub that file can't be found. The actual URL that did work contains e.g. a branch name etc, I don't know if the latest file can be fetched via multiple URLs. Anyway, not an LTSpice problem, if the URLs given to it do not work.

@Wissa - I don't have LTspice installed here, so I'll have to ask you: Now that you've removed the extraneous " which I mentioned from the example .txt file link in the question: (a) Are you saying LTspice v24 reports that it still could not open this .txt file link? (b) Are you saying that earlier LTspice versions can open that same file successfully? (c) Did the .lib file link in the question to github.com ever work?

wget http://raw.githubusercontent.com/wissa/LTSpice/main/MyLib/Diodes/1N4001.txt is able to retrieve the file. Albeit wget reports 301 Moved Permanently and then downloads https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wissa/LTSpice/main/MyLib/Diodes/1N4001.txt. I.e. uses https rather than http. Is LTSpice able to download the file if you change to use https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wissa/LTSpice/main/MyLib/Diodes/1N4001.txt as the URL?

@ChesterGillon - Thanks, the http vs. https difference was going to be my next question. This redirection (after receiving the HTTP 301 status) is something that web browsers do, but other programs might not. (If the OP confirms that is the problem, please do write it up as an actual answer, so it can be accepted. TY)

@Justme - Re: "not an LTSpice problem, if the URLs given to it do not work." I don't see things as so clear-cut. (a) Yes, it appears there were mistakes in the URLs in the original question. I quickly identified an issue with the .txt link which then worked in a browser. As you see, I've got an open request to the OP to clarify. (b) If mistakes in the question turn out to be the only issue (which seems unlikely, as the OP says problems only started in LTspice 24) then showing the user error would be an answer (just like a fixing an .trans syntax error) - not a reason to close the question.

Hi ALL,
The problem is still there. LTspice still give Could not open Include file msg
I corrected the links in the questions but the correct link originally were used in LTspice. So the question still valid

This is the error log output Fatal Error: Could not open include file "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/wissa/LTSpice/refs/heads/main/MyLib/Diodes/1N4001.txt"

@Wissa - Due to things changing, and a lack of some specific details, parts are still unclear for me e.g. Can any LTspice versions open that same file successfully? If so, which earlier LTspice version is successful? Also, did you read the comment by Chester Gillon? Did you try replacing "http" with "https" on that URL as suggested there? || Due to its removal from the question, I'm assuming you are not now asking about the original github.com link to a lib file, and are now only asking about the raw.githubusercontent.com link to the txt file. Is that correct?

Yes i did all the suggested comments above and nothing works. Regardless of the link github or raw.git ... the method is not working and we are looking for a solution. The raw one is better to be used as advised by the previous question

I have just tried with my LTSpice 17.0.30.0 it still works there with the http link. It does not with https. But that might be an issue because I am behind a corporate https proxy, which causes certificates to fail.

And I just installed LTSpice 24.0.12 and can confirm, that neither http or https works there for me. The documentation clearly states that it should be possible though. So this might be best handled with reporting a bug to Analog - at least it currently looks like one to me.
